# Can I use output of one kusto function as an input to other Kusto function?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Is there any way where I can use output of one Kusto function as input to another Kusto function ?

I have a query that is projecting some data. I basically want to use this data as input to another kusto function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See tabular functions and the last example in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/functions/user-defined-functions#invoking-a-user-defined-function) in the documentation.
For example:

```
let f1 = () { range x from 1 to 5 step 1 };
let f2 = (T:(x:long)) { T | extend y = x * 2 };
f1 | invoke f2()
```

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 10 |